# MySQL multiple indexes vs multi-column index for searching

Tags: mysql, indexing

In the software I'm writing one has the ability to search a given table for information. The search form has 5 fields, all which of course correspond to different columns in a table, but all of the fields are optional.

My question is in regard to whether or not multi-column indexing will work and the proper way to build a query for it.

If I have a single index across 5 columns, and I build a query to search them, when it comes to fields in this index I'm not searching, do I do something like:

`field1` = 10 AND `field2` > 0 AND ...

Or should I not include the unused columns at all?

I've searched around for information about multiple column indices, but I can't seem to find what to do when you need to skip one of the columns in a given index or if you simply don't care about that one in that specific instance.

Comment: it depends...on the query workload

Comment: Do everything you can to avoid table scans. This is when a query has nothing to index off of. Never use table scans unless the tables rows are a fixed length, and is small. Like 1-20 rows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to understand in MySQL (in the case of InnoDB) it only uses the left most prefix of your indexes. So if the index is in Field1 + Field2, querying with only Field2 in the **WHERE** cannot make use of the whole index.

And if `Field1 + Field2 + Field3` is the index, a query with only `Field1 & Field3` in **WHERE** the same would happen.

**Option 1**

You would have to create a separate index for each search scenario if you want to optimize each search. However, if the tables are large, then the indexes would become extremely large as well. **If those search queries are made very often this would be worth it.**

**Option 2**

You can use a nifty trick if your searches have a *low selectivity* (i.e. Gender) by putting the low selectivity columns to the left most and use `Gender IN(M, F)` to include it in the **WHERE** clause along with the other column(s) to make use of the whole index.

Answer (score 3):

For query with criteria

```
field1 = 10 AND field2 > 0
```

you need to have composite index `field1 + field2` (in this particular order)

Comment: so index is not used if querying only field2. So if the queries can be anything, its better to have individual indexes.

Comment: @kaka: nope. This index will be used if both fields take part in query, or only `field1`. For different queries there are some tricks, except of N single indexes

Comment: @kaka, that's correct because they are pre-ordered as field1, then field2. Indices in MySQL are read from left to right.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your queries. If you will be doing many queries with field1 and field2 often, then it makes sense to have a composite index. Otherwise you might get by fine on multiple single column indices.